# Responsive images have undesired rendering on most browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design

I’m trying to produce a web page layout that, when you resize the
height of the browser, the images all scale up or down depending on
the height. In the following example I have the images being 10% of
the height of the window.

HTML snippet:

```
<ul class="image-list">
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image"
         height="200" width="300"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/1/" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image"
         height="200" width="300"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/2/" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image"
         height="200" width="300"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/3/" />
  </li>
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image"
         height="200" width="300"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/4/" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.image-list {
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.image-list__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid hotpink;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.image-list__image {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/casr/pen/ojyrn/

I’ve attached real renderings of the web browsers below but
here is a summary of in the 4 browsers I have tested (*Chrome*,
*Firefox*, *IE* and *Safari*):

- *Chrome*, *IE* and *Safari* are able to render the desired look on
  page load/refresh. *Safari*, however, is the only browser able
  to maintain the desired render when the browser window’s
  height is adjusted. *Firefox* has a padding inside the container
  when the page is loaded.
- *Chrome* breaks the aspect ratio of the image on shrink. On
  expansion, the image breaks out of the pink container. Shrinking
  or expanding does not change the width of the pink container.
- *Firefox* and *IE* do not change the width of the pink container as
  the height changes, however, the images’ heights adjust
  properly and the aspect ratio is maintained.

If you have any ideas about how to fix this or any suggestions at
all I’d love to have a discussion. It’s driving me nuts!

---

[image: Chrome 35.0.1916.153 (OS X 10.9.4)]

---

[image: Firefox 30.0 (OS X 10.9.4)]

---

[image: Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17107 (Windows 8.1 Pro)]

---

[image: Safari 7.0.5 (OS X 10.9.4)]

Comment: To start, remove the image dimensions from the HTML/inline CSS.

Comment: I’ve made a reduced example here to demonstrate but in the working
version I have quite a lot of thumbnails that are loaded and putting
in the dimensions speeds up the initial render of the page.

Comment: Yes, but it's fundamental to responsive images that they do NOT have defined dimensions.

Comment: Sorry @Paulie_D, I’ve not experienced this. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following pen:

http://codepen.io/atcwells/pen/ovCpb

Is this what you mean? Paulie_D is correct, you cannot use absolute heights/widths on images if you want it to be responsive. CSS only listed below for brevity (and height sized up because my poor old eyes couldn't cope).

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.image-list {
  height: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}

.image-list__item {
  border: 5px solid hotpink;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.image-list__image {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still suffers from the same problem for me as when the images are resized the containing element does not shrink/expand to contain the image. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you attached to using Lists? It would seem that what you're after is just a border/margin around your images to allow them to flow properly. Check the following to see what I mean: http://codepen.io/atcwells/pen/ovCpb

Comment: Only in so much as it seemed more semantic but I’m willing to concede. I’m going to see how well it fits in with the rest of things but that demo is definitely promising. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It turned out that lists weren’t to blame by themselves – I tried using `<button>` too to no avail. Like you discovered, images on their own got you most of the way there. Unfortunately I had a hidden requirement to have an overlay (like a transparent background over the top of the image) that as far as I can tell requires the additional element. I ended up opting for a media query based approach which isn’t fluid. Not perfect but... deadlines!  

Thanks for the help anyway. Gave me some good clues to explore!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t manage to get fluid images working in the way that I
needed for my requirements (although do check welale’s answer for
an alternative). Instead I opted for `@media` queries to snap the
height at different points.

Check out the pen if you want a play or see below for the code.

Pen: http://codepen.io/casr/pen/FGsvK

HTML snippet:

```
<ul class="image-list">
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image" height="200"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/1/" width="300">
  </li>
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image" height="200"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/2/" width="300">
  </li>
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image" height="200"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/3/" width="300">
  </li>
  <li class="image-list__item">
    <img class="image-list__image" height="200"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/sports/4/" width="300">
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.image-list {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.image-list__item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid hotpink;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.image-list__image {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 320px) {
  .image-list__image {
    height: 35px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 480px) {
  .image-list__image {
    height: 70px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 800px) {
  .image-list__image {
    height: 130px;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```